# ServiceUnavailable: 503 DNS resolution failed for service: firestore.googleapis.com

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access the Google's Firestore in my project with Python code (in Jupyter Notebook) and for some reason the Python program never finishes.
Also tried to create a document in Firestore but then I get this error:

```
ServiceUnavailable: 503 DNS resolution failed for service: firestore.googleapis.com
```

I created a service account in Firestore (ServiceAccount.json contains the settings). This is my code:

```
import firebase_admin

from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('ServiceAccount.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
db.collection('company').add({'name': 'Test'})
```

Only the last statement fails.
This is also returned:

```
_InactiveRpcError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py in error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     65         try:
---> 66             return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     67         except grpc.RpcError as exc:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in __call__(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
    945                                       wait_for_ready, compression)
--> 946         return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
    947 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
    848     else:
--> 849         raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
    850 

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "DNS resolution failed for service: firestore.googleapis.com"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1632831473.221000000","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":1356,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1632831473.221000000","description":"DNS resolution failed for service: firestore.googleapis.com","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/native/dns_resolver.cc","file_line":202,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1632831473.221000000","description":"OS Error","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/resolve_address_windows.cc","file_line":93,"os_error":"The specified class was not found.\r\n","syscall":"getaddrinfo","wsa_error":10109}]}]}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ServiceUnavailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py in retry_target(target, predicate, sleep_generator, deadline, on_error)
    189         try:
--> 190             return target()
    191
...
```

Comment: if I try to check IP for `firestore.googleapis.com` (Linux: `whois firestore.googleapis.com`) then it shows that this address doesn't exists. Maybe they changed something and it needs to update module or file `.json`. OR maybe it is only temporary problem with server and you have to wait few days and it will work again.

Comment: When I ping firestore.googleapis.com I do get a response: 
`C:\>ping firestore.googleapis.com

Pinging firestore.googleapis.com [142.251.36.42] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 142.251.36.42: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=117
Reply from 142.251.36.42: bytes=32 time=26ms TTL=117
Reply from 142.251.36.42: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=117
Reply from 142.251.36.42: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=117

Ping statistics for 142.251.36.42:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 18ms, Maximum = 26ms, Average = 20ms`

Comment: But still my Python code freezes (in case of a get()) or the same error is returned when I try to create data.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Windows? If you are, I believe you have hit a [bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/18691). Although the c-ares DNS resolver issue was fixed, you might be using an older package.

You can resolve this by checking the environment variables you have configured. If you run this in one of the Jupyter Notebook cells:

```
import os
os.environ
```

You should get a long list of variables. Look to see what the `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER` is:

```
environ{'SHELL': '/bin/bash',
        'OS_IMAGE_FAMILY': 'debian-10',
        'CONDA_EXE': '/opt/conda/bin/conda',
        '_CE_M': '',
        'DL_ANACONDA_HOME': '/opt/conda',
```

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/environment_variables.md):

> GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER Declares which DNS resolver to use. The default is ares if gRPC is built with c-ares support. Otherwise, the value of this environment variable is ignored. Available DNS resolver include:

> ares (default on most platforms except iOS, Android or Node)- a DNS resolver based around the c-ares library

> native - a DNS resolver based around getaddrinfo(), creates a new thread to perform name resolution

You can then set the `GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER` like this to native:

```
os.environ['GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER'] = 'native'
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will test this. Indeed, it's on a Windows computer. In the meantime I also tested my code on a Mac and there is runs smoothly.

Comment: That's good news. I believe iOS uses native anyway as ares is not the default for Mac as per the docs. Let me know how the tests go as I would be interested to know the results.

Comment: Hi Andrew, no luck. First of all os.environ didn't show a GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER setting. Second, after executing os.environ['GRPC_DNS_RESOLVER'] = 'native' and running my code again, code for retrieving data still never ends and doesn't return any data. (I am using my work computer w or w/o VPN on and Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda or VS Code)

Comment: That's a shame. What about after restarting the Kernal? Is Anaconda and Jupyter notebook running locally or in a container? Do you have access to the [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) in the browser? I am wondering if you can dig into the request headers under the network tab and see more detail of the 503 error. Might be worth a look.

Comment: After restarting kernel still no luck. Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook and VS Code all running locally on my laptop. Will do some further research.

Comment: Can't see any relevant information with developers tools. Will add screenshot in additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because I used `firebase-admin==4.0.1`.
After upgrade `firebase-admin==6.1.0` it successfully connected to Google's Firestore servers from my local server.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error because of an internet connection. So check if your device is able to reach any other website.